# columns: Datagridview to Datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatables

I am facing this issue, I have datagridview and a datatable.

```
        VPfn_CreateDataGrid();//This fuction creates gridview columns
        DataTable invoice_table = (DataTable)invoice_data.DataSource;
```

now First thing, datagridview is empty when form loads. What I am trying to do is adding data to datagridview via multiple textboxes and combomoxes and for that I am using datatable.

```
        private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow x = invoice_table.NewRow();
        x["serial_number"] = tsr.Text.ToString();
        x["item"] = combo_items.SelectedItem.ToString();
        x["item_rate"] = tr.Text;
        x["item_qty"] = tq.Text;
        x["item_unit"] = combo_unit.SelectedItem.ToString();
        x["item_vat"] = combo_vat.SelectedItem.ToString();
        x["amount"] = ta.Text;

        invoice_table.Rows.Add(x);
        invoice_data.Refresh();

    }
```

And the error is "Column 'serial_number' does not belong to table"

Comment: from the error it seems column binding value has the issue. use the proper binding value

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create a the data table with the specific column. while your datagridview is empty the DataTable also will be empty.

```
DataTable invoice_table = (DataTable)invoice_data.DataSource;
```

infront of this..
while loading your form you can create datatable with the columns.

```
DataTable invoice_table; //Global
private void load()
{
   invoice_table = new DataTable();
   invoice_table.Columns.Add("serial_number", typeof(int));
   invoice_table.Columns.Add("item");
   .....
}
```

after that

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow x = invoice_table.NewRow();
    x["serial_number"] = tsr.Text.ToString();
    x["item"] = combo_items.SelectedItem.ToString();
    x["item_rate"] = tr.Text;
    x["item_qty"] = tq.Text;
    x["item_unit"] = combo_unit.SelectedItem.ToString();
    x["item_vat"] = combo_vat.SelectedItem.ToString();
    x["amount"] = ta.Text;

    invoice_table.Rows.Add(x);
    invoice_data.Refresh();
}
```

Try this...

Comment: Actually I the function it self creating columns in datagridview cant it be automatically created in datatable?private void VPfn_CreateDataGrid()
        {
            invoice_data.ColumnCount = 7;

            invoice_data.Columns[0].Name = "Sr.";
            invoice_data.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Sr.";
            invoice_data.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "serial_number";
            invoice_data.Columns[0].Width = 30;
            invoice_data.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;

Comment: can you send your source code. coz your comment is not clear, to understand.  please try to follow the instruction before command or asking questions.